# How do you sum **sub-elements** of a JSON field?

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb

In PostgreSQL, how do you sum **sub-elements** of a JSON field?

Given: `Customer <--- Order`

where `Order` has a **JSON field** `quantities_per_product` that contains the qty and shipped qty for each product of the `Order`.

I'd like to get a summary per `Customer` of the quantities for each product for all the customer's orders.

**Example:**

```
Customer 1

> Order 1
quantities_per_product
{
    "product_A": {"qty": 10, "shipped": 5}
    "product_B": {"qty": 20, "shipped": 2}
}


> Order 2
quantities_per_product
{
    "product_A": {"qty": 15, "shipped": 8}
    "product_C": {"qty": 7, "shipped": 1}
}
```

Expected result for Customer 1:

```
quantities_per_product_summary
{
    "product_A": {"qty": 25, "shipped": 13}
    "product_B": {"qty": 20, "shipped": 2}
    "product_C": {"qty": 7, "shipped": 1}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query achieves your given objective:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object('quantities_per_product'
                        , jsonb_object_agg(k, jsonb_build_object('qty', q, 'shipped', s)))
FROM  (
   SELECT k, sum((v->>'qty')::int) AS q, sum((v->>'shipped')::int) AS s
   FROM   orders o, jsonb_each(o.quantities_per_product) q(k,v)
   GROUP  BY k
   ) sub;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zHgC__dY)

The task would be so much simpler and cheaper with a properly normalized DB schema. Storing your orders in JSON format is highly inefficient for storage, and performance. And does not allow to enforce constraints and referential integrity. See:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26704636/939860)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to adapt it to regroup per customer but having some difficulties: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZRmyqklr. Where should the grouping per customer be?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it? Does that look right? https://dbfiddle.uk/ZzclCTpt

Comment: @Michael: Basically, yes. I would aggregate first and join later. Cheaper. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/1wGJcRO0 And: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468034/939860

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. :)